# Deep copying and nested arrays

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, deep-copy

```
clone(){
let clone = new individual;
clone.chromosome = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.chromosome))
clone.resultatVal= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.resultatVal))
clone.fitnessVal = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.fitnessVal))

return clone;
```

//first instance

```
let indv1 = new individual
let indv2 = indv1.clone()
```

//second instance:

```
let pop1 = new population(10000,10);
pop1.individualsinitialise();
pop1.survivalselection();

for(let i=0; i<2; i++){
pop1.individualAdd(pop1.individuals[0].clone());
pop1.survivalselection();
}
```

The code for survivalSelection:

```
survivalSelection(){
            let individualsWork = this.clone().individuals;
            let fitnessValues = []
            let nLargestFitnessValues = []
            let indexsOfnLargestFitnessValues = [];
            //find nFitness values from population

            for (let i = 0; i<this.individuals.length; i++){
                nLargestFitnessValues.push(individualsWork[i].fitnessVal);
                fitnessValues.push(individualsWork[i].fitnessVal)
            };
    
            nLargestFitnessValues = nLargestFitnessValues.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a - b;
            }).reverse().slice(0,this.n);
    
    
            //find indexs of nFitnessValues
            for (let i=0; i<this.n;i++){
                indexsOfnLargestFitnessValues.push(fitnessValues.indexOf(nLargestFitnessValues[i]));
            }
    
            //find chromosomes of nFitnessValues
            //empty individuals
            this.individuals = [];
    
            for(let i=0; i<this.n; i++){
                this.individuals.push(individualsWork[indexsOfnLargestFitnessValues[i]]);
            };
```

Can anyone explain this? In the first instance it works as it should, it deep copies. And on the second instance it doesnt work. The arrays end up having same references, which can be seen on the picture where i have edited one with a random value and all three get that same value.

I have been searching around and havent found anything on this.

Comment: please post code as text and not as image ...

Comment: What does `pop1.individualAdd` do? `clone()` will create a new object without any doubt and also the properties of that object won't share any references with prexisting objects. So the only point where this can get messed up is `individualAdd`

Comment: BTW the shared code for `clone` obviously uses wrong variable names and also has invalid syntax. You should be more careful when posting code ...

Comment: pop1.individualAdd does simply just push the Individual into an the array "Individuals"
Survivalselection just gets the 10 individuals with highest fitness

Derpirscher

Comment: i am confused can you see the three pictures i posted? I cant myself

Comment: How does it use wrong variable names and invalid syntax?

Comment: you are assigning `clone.chromosome` 3 times. furthermore it's `JSON.parse` not `JSON.Parse`

Comment: individualAdd(x){
this.individuals.push(x);
}

thats it - and the population class which it is a method of has individuals as an array

Comment: My bad, in my code it is not clone.chromosome 3 times, and it is JSON.parse (Let me change that quickly on this post)

Comment: Then either `pop1.individuals[0].clone()` is not calling the shown `clone()` method but something else or `survivalselection`is messing with your values ... post the code of this method also ...

Comment: hmm, do you have any guesses as to how that is so? I am 99% sure that pop1.individuals[0] is of the individual class. with the .clone() method

Comment: Post the code of `survivalselection` and add some debug output to `clone` to see if it's called

Comment: okay, i will. Give me a minute - appreciate your time :)

Comment: clone is called, i've just tested

Comment: I have posted the code for survivalSelection

Comment: hey @derpirscher you still here

Comment: `indexsOfnLargestFitnessValues.push(fitnessValues.indexOf(nLargestFitnessValues[i]));` will be a problem if multiple individuals have the same `fitnesValues` (which they have if you are cloning them). Because `indexOf` will always find the first element in the array with that specifc value. Thus, if all three elements in the array have the same fitnessvalue, you will always take the very first element ... Attach a debugger, you will probably see, that `indexsOfnLargestFitnessValues` contains the same index multiple times

Comment: Actually your complete `survivalselection` seems overly complicated. Why not just `this.individuals = this.indiviuals.sort((a, b) => b.fitnessValue - a.fitnessValue).slice(0, this.n)`, ie a one-liner instead of that whole function?

Comment: No good reason. I am just very new to programming. That looks promissing i will do that. Thanks :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.